# mailgun sending emails to spam for company email id

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, mailgun

mailgun is sending mails but the mails are going to spam only for company email id and for gmail, yahoo mail and rediffmail its going to inbox how can i fix this? please help.

i have tested for the content of the using mail tester but it but it tells mail is not spam having junk i got 9.2 out of 10

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config= array();
$config= $this->mail_config();
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from($template->from_email);
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->bcc($template->bcc);
$this->email->subject($cust_subject);
$this->email->message($email_content);
$this->email->attach($path);
if($this->email->send()){
$data = 1;
}
```

i dont understand why it does that only for the company email id , when it works fine for gmail, yahoo mail and rediffmail

Answer (score 0):

> A primary reason your messages are getting sorted into spam is the sorting and filtering processes of the recipient's mailserver.

https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011702394-Why-Do-My-Emails-Go-to-Spam-